# Prolog declaring a variable

Tags: variables, prolog, declare

Is it possible to declare a variable to a fact?

```
male(tom).
male(Tom) := male(tom).
```

So that the capital Tom variable is set. Prolog set capital letters as variable and I don't understand how to make it work like that since that is what my Professor wants us to do.

Comment: Well.... Prolog isn't Pascal. ;) If you have the fact `male(tom).` asserted, then if you query, `male(Tom).` then you will get `Tom = tom`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare `male(Tom) := male(tom).`

If you have declared `male(tom).`, then by typing the query `male(Tom).` , you'll get

```
2 ?- male(Tom).
Tom = tom.
```

just like @mbratch said.

It works the same with any name for your variable:

```
3 ?- male(X).
X = tom.

4 ?- male(Tommmmm).
Tommmmm = tom.

5 ?- male(Name).
Name = tom.
```